# Why do my Steam games not Accelerate?

Tags: ati, games, steam

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS alongside Windows 7 on my old Toshiba Satellite L505D-GS6000. From what I remember, this computer performed pretty fairly on the same game (Garry's Mod) in Windows.

I installed steam, then installed Garry's Mod, and started up. The menu was fine, but then when the map started, it lagged so much I had to hard reset the computer.

How can I increase the AMD graphical acceleration to a tolerable level? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There's a easy way you can know if you have Hardware Acceleration:

```
glxinfo | grep render
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on ATI RV515
```

If direct rendering is "No" or the renderer string contains "llvm" you are pretty sure you don't have hardware acceleration.

If both are OK, then is the games implementation (or wine) that doesn't support hardware acceleration. If your card supports it you can try installing the latest fglxr drivers but I wouldn't recommend it if everything else is fine.

Comment: Okay, so I believe i have done what you asked, let me know if this is right.

    direct rendering: Yes
    OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS880
    GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, GL_NV_conditional_render,

Comment: The thing is, I didn't use wine. I just let steam install the game. it was one of the few Linux games I owned, and it ran without hesitation.
So say I needed to install those new drivers, How may I proceed?

Comment: @ColbySolomon there are couple of questions in ask ubuntu covering that.